# image location double slash

Tags: java, image, imageicon

```
            String s;
            JFileChooser jfc = new JFileChooser();
            jfc.showDialog(jfc, "Choose an image file");
            s = jfc.getSelectedFile().getAbsolutePath();
            tx_image.setText(s);
```

i use file chooser to get the location of image. then i saved it in the database. the location it saves is of type c:\doucuments\3.jpg . and then i used imageicon in JLabel display the image through that location

```
 Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
                Connection con =DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:project","sa","123456");
                String s=tx_name.getText();
                Statement stmt= con.createStatement();
                ResultSet rs=stmt.executeQuery("SELECT name,address,email,startdate,enddate,reason,homeph,cellph,hourlyrate,image FROM driver");
                while(rs.next())
                {
                    if(s.equals(rs.getString(1)))
                    {
                        tx_address.setText(rs.getString(2));
                        tx_email.setText(rs.getString(3));
                        tx_startdate.setText(rs.getString(4));
                        tx_enddate.setText(rs.getString(5));
                        txf_reason.setText(rs.getString(6));
                        tx_homeph.setText(Integer.toString(rs.getInt(7)));
                        tx_cellph.setText(Integer.toString(rs.getInt(8)));
                        tx_hourlyrate.setText(Integer.toString(rs.getInt(9)));
                        s=rs.getString(10);
                        ic=new ImageIcon(s);
                        lb_image.setIcon(ic);
                        lb_image.setBounds(350,100,200,200);
                        break;
```

so the problem is that image location which imageicon is giving an error because the image location which imageicon require is of type c:\documents\3.jpg so. so how can i use the file chooser to save that double slash location instead of the single slash.

Comment: 1) Please add an upper case letter at the start of sentences.  Also use a capital for the word I, and abbreviations and acronyms like JEE or WAR.  This makes it easier for people to understand and help. 2) For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: Why don't you replace the single slash by a double slash, before you hstore the path into your database?

Comment: @reporter i know this can be done but i want to remove this issue, every time i have to enter the location i have to remove the single slash by double slash....